# Get the absolute row number in a grid

Tags: gridview, yii

In yii's **CGridView** I can get the current row number by using **$row**. But this returns the row index within the current page only. What I really need is to get the absolute row number among all pages.

I am using yii, so my dreams should come true "easily", so I expect the answer should not guide me to add a special field to the data provider or access the pager and get the current page number and then multiply numbers bla bla bla.

Thanks

Comment: Great question. I'm curious: for what purpose do you need this? I'm guessing it's going to require a little custom code because your problem is located in the DataProvider (it does the pagination, not CGridView).

Comment: @DV98, thanks for your feedback and your info about the DataProvider. I just need to add a sequence number to the grid. Fair enough, huh?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you solved this? If not, I offer you the following solution

```
$this->widget(
  'zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',
  array(
    'columns'=>array(
      array(
        'header'=>'No.',
        'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
      ),
    ),
  ));
```

basically you can access the currentpage and pagesize variables from the dataprovider and you use it to calculate the 'row number' for the whole data. Why the $row + 1? because $row starts from 0. Hope this helps :D

Comment: Champion, champion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
CDataProvider has a property "totalItemCount" which can be used:

Ex: $this->grid->dataProvider->getTotalItemCount();

More details at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#totalItemCount-detail