# I want to get the page number of the CGridview when a button on the page is clicked?

Tags: yii

I want to print the CGridview page which contain totally 360 results with 10 results per page I need a button in the same page which prints the results of current 10 page as pdf?

the problem is I don't know how to access the appropriate page . suppose if I am in the page with results 250 to 260. The button in the page should prints only the current page to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the best method for that as it's updated via ajax and I don't think there's any indication given for you to grab the page number for use in a link.

I don't know if it'd work in your situation but one workaround might be to use javascript to detect which of the pagination list items has the 'selected' class applied?

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('grabPageNo', "
    $('#getPageNum').on('click', function(event){
        var pageNumber = $('.yiiPager > .selected > a').html();
        alert('page is: '+pageNumber);
    });
");

echo CHtml::button('get page number',array('id'=>'getPageNum'));
```

Clicking the button in the above code should give you the current page number if you're using all the default CGridView options. You could then append that to a URL or similar, depending on how you're working your button.

**EDIT**

Actually, there's some interesting reading here: [How to return to current page in GridView?](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/20512-how-to-return-to-current-page-in-gridview/) Which recommends uing an [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rrviews/). And also in the answer to this question on SO: [Get the absolute row number in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834522/get-the-absolute-row-number-in-a-grid)

Comment: Thanks Stu. But it displays only page is: null.